# achartengine: use addYTextLabel() => setShowGrid() doesn't work

Tags: android, achartengine

I create a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer, i customed values of the label on Y with something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbYLabels; i++) {
     renderer.addYTextLabel(i, i+"%");
}
```

(Same kind of trick for the X axis)

But a side effect is the properties bellow don't work anymore.

```
 renderer.setShowGrid(showGrid);
 renderer.setShowGridX(true);
 renderer.setShowGridY(true);
```

The grid isn't showing anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
renderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
```